# Using AUTOFILTER to copy filtered data to the bottom of a list (different Excel Sheet) without Header Row

Tags: excel, autofilter

I am using AUTOFILTER to filter data on one Excel worksheet (Input_Wkr_Hrs) and append the data to the bottom of a list (table) on another worksheet (Output) in the same workbook. The problem I have is that when the data gets added to the bottom of the list, it includes the HEADER ROW Names. How do you copy filtered data using AUTOFILTER and not include the HEADER NAMES when appending to the bottom of a list?

The source table on the worksheet (Input_Wkr_Hrs) has three columns (Emp Name, Section, Hours).

I am in the beginning stages of learning Excel VBA; this is my first question on Stackoverflow.
***Code*** below

Sub GetWorkerData()
    ' shImput_Wkr_Hrs  name if source data sheet
    ' shOutout  name of destination sheet
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = shImput_Wkr_Hrs.Range("C15").CurrentRegion
    '
    'TurnOffFunctionality ' Turn off Screen updating and other stuff

```
With rg
    .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=">0"    ' filter working hrs hours >0
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy    'Destination:=shOutput.Range("a1")
    '
    '.Offset(1).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    shOutput.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

'
        rg.AutoFilter
    End With
     '
    shOutput.Activate
    'TurnOnFunctionality ' Turn on Screen updating and other stuff
End Sub

Comment: I screwed up pasting the code into my question... sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that ws_Data contains the data that you would like to filter/copy and ws_Output is the worksheet where the data will be pasted.

```
Dim rng_Visible as Range, outputLastRow as long
' Assume that the first line is the header
With ws_Data
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">0"

    ' Check if there is data to copy
    If .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1 > 0 Then
        Set rng_Visible = .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Resize(.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        ' Copy the visible filtered range
        rng_Visible.Copy

        ' Find the last row in Output worksheet using column A, make sure the column you use does not have any blank value in middle
         outputLastRow= ws_Output.Cells(ws_Output.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

         ' Paste to the output worksheet starting from column A
         ws_Output.Range("A" & outputLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
         Application.CutCopyMode = False

         ' Turn off the auto filter 
         ws_Data.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If

End With
```

Comment: Hello RuanRuan, thank you for the help. I get Object variable or with block variable not set error on line: "If .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1). SpecialCells etc. "

Comment: Hi, I double checked the code and it worked well. Did you assign values to ws_Data and ws_Output?  One more thing, you should change ("A" & outputLastRow) to ("A" & outputLastRow+1) otherwise the code will overlapped the last line.